# Move files with specific number of characters in the extension

Tags: command-line, mv

How do I move all files that only have three characters in the extension to the parent directory?

E.g. I want to move all the .mp3 and .zip but not all the .sh to the parent directory.

Comment: `.jpeg` extension does not exist. Generally, the extension is `jpg`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
mv *.mp3 *.zip /destination/
```

if you really meant 3 characters:

```
mv *.??? /destination
```

but this will also do .xml or .mov or .mp4.

Tip: you can use `ls` to see what files are shown that will be moved when using `mv`

If you want to move large numbers of files use...

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -iname '*.mp3' -exec mv -t /destination/ {} +
```

Comment: @Rizwind Since Questioner didn't say whether there were a few files, many files, or millions of files, the alternative form might be better `mv -t .. *.mp3 *.zip`. Although, for millions of files, `find` piped to `xargs`, and the `mv -t /destination` is da bomb.

Comment: I use `echo mv ...` for testing. It lets me see the exact command, and if I like the looks, a simple `^echo ^^` runs the `mv`.

Comment: @waltinator I totally agree :D but the question was too simple for a find+xargs :D Added ;)

Comment: @Rizwind `-maxdepth 1` should be close to the directory, before the `-iname '*.mp3'`, and you should use single quotes to avoid the wildcard from matching files in the current directory..

Comment: @Rizwind Thanks! :D mv *.??+ /destination was exactly whati was looking for.